# Envoy Proxy: Is it possible to create an basic auth with .htpasswd like in nginx?

Tags: nginx, nginx-reverse-proxy, nginx-config, envoyproxy

I have an `nginx.conf` with basic auth like this:

```
location / {
            auth_basic           "Prometheus";
            auth_basic_user_file /etc/nginx/.htpasswd;
            proxy_pass http://localhost:9090/;
        }
```

Is it possible to create an basic auth config for envoy like in nginx?

This is my envoy.yaml:

```
admin:
  address:
    socket_address:
      protocol: TCP
      address: 0.0.0.0
      port_value: 9901
static_resources:
  listeners:
  - name: listener_0
    address:
      socket_address:
        protocol: TCP
        address: 0.0.0.0
        port_value: 10000
    filter_chains:
    - filters:
      - name: envoy.filters.network.http_connection_manager
        typed_config:
          "@type": type.googleapis.com/envoy.extensions.filters.network.http_connection_manager.v3.HttpConnectionManager
          stat_prefix: ingress_http
          route_config:
            name: local_route
            virtual_hosts:
            - name: local_service
              domains: ["*"]
              routes:
              - match:
                  prefix: "/"
                route:
                  cluster: service_envoyproxy_io
          http_filters:
          - name: envoy.filters.http.router
      transport_socket:
        name: envoy.transport_sockets.tls
        typed_config:
          "@type": type.googleapis.com/envoy.extensions.transport_sockets.tls.v3.DownstreamTlsContext
          common_tls_context:
            tls_params:
              tls_minimum_protocol_version: TLSv1_2
              tls_maximum_protocol_version: TLSv1_3
              cipher_suites: "[ECDHE-RSA-AES256-GCM-SHA384|ECDHE-RSA-AES128-GCM-SHA256]"
            tls_certificates:
              - certificate_chain: { filename: "/etc/ssl/prometheus.crt" }
                private_key: { filename: "/etc/ssl/prometheus.key" }    
  clusters:
  - name: service_envoyproxy_io
    connect_timeout: 30s
    type: STATIC
    # Comment out the following line to test on v6 networks
   # dns_lookup_family: V4_ONLY
    lb_policy: ROUND_ROBIN
    load_assignment:
      cluster_name: service_envoyproxy_io
      endpoints:
      - lb_endpoints:
        - endpoint:
            address:
              socket_address:
                address: 0.0.0.0
                port_value: 9090
```

I found basic_auth module in envoy-Doku: [Envoy Basic Auth Module](https://jteso.github.io/envoy/documentation/site/modules/basic_auth/), but the strings are hardcoded....not the best way in my opinion!

Many thanks for help!